# How to convert a PDF document to JPG using ImageMagick and Perl

Tags: perl, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to convert a pdf into a jpg, but I keep getting an error and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

`form.pm`:

```
 my $filename = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\students.jpg";
  my $pdfname = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\students.pdf";

  open(my $fh, '<', $pdfname);
  binmode($fh); 

  system('"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.6.2-Q16\\convert.exe" "' . $pdfname . '" -quality 60 -resize 256x335 "' . $filename . '"');
  return "success";
```

I did a test thru the command line and is working fine, but from the file don't work.

Comment: Why are you opening the file `$pdfname` if you only use it as parameter in the systtem command line?

Comment: Have you tried the list form of `system()?` I.e. `system(qw(C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.6.2-Q16\\convert.exe), $pdfname, qw(-quality 60 -resize 256x335), $filename)` You should also add an error check to `system()`.

Answer (score 2):

A few things...

Firstly, remove the following lines - they are not needed:

```
open(my $fh, '<', $pdfname);
binmode($fh);
```

---

Secondly, your ImageMagick version is **ancient** - it must be 7+ years old. Consider updating it - it is free.

---

Thirdly, **ImageMagick** uses **ghostscript** to read PDF files - technically it *"delegates"* to **ghostscript**. In order for that work, it needs to be able to find **ghostscript** and I guess that is the issue. In the **Command Prompt** you probably have your `PATH` set to include the directory that contains **ghostscript** but Perl's `system()` command probably sets a different `PATH` that doesn't include that directory, so it can't be found.

There are a couple of options but I am not that good on Windows, so you may need to work with me or someone else to get them working...

The simplest is probably to find where `ghostscript` is installed, and then **make a backup of** and edit the file called `delegates.xml` in your **ImageMagick** directory and find the line that looks like this:

```
<delegate decode="pdf" encode="eps" mode="bi" command="&quot;gs&quot;  ...
```

and introduce the full path in front of the `gs` part, to end up with something like:

```
<delegate decode="pdf" encode="eps" mode="bi" command="&quot;/full/path/to/gs&quot; ...
```

The other option is to change your `system()` call in Perl, so you set the PATH to include ghostscript before you run **ImageMagick**. I have no idea how you would quote that, but you would want to run:

```
system("set PATH=C:\path\to\ghostscript\dir;C:\path\to\ImageMagick\dir;%PATH%  && convert.exe YOURDOC.PDF -quality -resize widthxheight OUTPUT.PDF")
```